# Accessing view reference in TAL with "python" namespace prefix

Tags: python, template-tal, zpt

How to access `view` reference (and its members) when `TAL` is used with `python` namespace prefix?

For example, I got reference on `records` property of the current `view`:

```xml
<tal:block define="record view/records">
```

How do I achieve the same with `python` modifier:

```xml
<tal:block define="python: ....">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use attribute access:

```
<tal:block define="python:view.records">
```

If `records` is a method, make sure to *call* it:

```
<tal:block define="python:view.records()">
```